# Json - JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I'm new to JSON. I'm trying to read the String in JSON but it throw me an error.

```
String strResponse = "{"IndustryList" : [{"industryId" : "1","industryName" : "Bird Nest","industryStatus" : "0","industryDescription" : "Bird nest industry","industryIconFilepath" : "","industryIconFilename" : ""},{"industryId" : "2","industryName" : "Medicine","industryStatus" : "0","industryDescription" : "Medicine Products","industryIconFilepath" : "","industryIconFilename" : ""}]}"

JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(strResponse);
JSONArray nameArray = json_data.names(); 
JSONArray valArray = json_data.toJSONArray(nameArray);
Log.i(MainActivity.class.getName(),
             "Number of entries " + valArray.length());
for (int i = 0; i < valArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = valArray.getJSONObject(i);
    Log.i(MainActivity.class.getName(), jsonObject.getString("text"));
}
```

Error:

```
at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: The first line of your code doesn't contain a valid Java String, JSON or not.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the JSON framework you use and at which line exactly you ge the exception? Note that the more effort you put into the question the more effort people will put into their answers.

Comment: actually I get the response from web service. I convert the Object response to string. This is what I get when convert from Object response to String.

Comment: i get the error at.. JSONObject jsonObject = valArray.getJSONObject(i);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `toJSONArray` returns array of values. And it has only 1 element - `industryList` value. Which is array itself. So you need to iterate  throw `valArray.getJSONArray(0)` not through `valArray`

Comment: do you mean that I need to change my for loop from valArray.length() to valArray.getJSONArray(0)...

Comment: Yes. Or you can make this: `JSONArray valArray = json_data.toJSONArray(nameArray).getJSONArray(0);`

Comment: @China_82 Why do you use `names` to get all keys in json object? Why don't you use names directly, like `JSONArray valArray = json_data.getJSONObject('industryList');`?

Comment: I got Type mismatch: cannot convert from JSONObject to JSONArray when i use JSONArray valArray = json_data.getJSONObject("industryList");

Comment: @chinna_82 sorry, `getJSONArray("industryList")`